# Objects of categories with no morphisms from them other than endomorphisms

Tags: category-theory, universal-property, morphism

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a category. My question is the following. *Is there a name for an object $\zeta \in \mathrm{ob}(\mathcal{C})$ such that, for every object $X \neq \zeta$, there exists no morphism $f: \zeta \rightarrow X$?*

This seems to be a different approach to initial objects.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Notice that, from the perspective of category theory, the property you propose is not very natural, because it is not invariant under equivalence. However, we may rephrase it to be more natural by instead asking for an object $\zeta$ such that every morphism $\zeta \to X$ is an isomorphism. These are known as [maximal objects](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/maximal+object). One common class of examples is given by [strict terminal objects](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/strict+terminal+object).

Comment: This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, it would be better to look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements. Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/) regarding quality standards.

Comment: @Shaun I respect the sentiment, but this is a straightforward question that would not necessarily benefit from further context. It is a request for a piece of jargon, not a "do my homework" question

Comment: @varkor Did you mean it is not invariant under *equivalence* (i.e. it is evil)? I haven't checked it yet but it seems very obviously invariant under isomorphism

Comment: My mistake! Thank you, @FShrike. Sorry, varkor.

Comment: @FShrike: yes I did, thank you :)

Comment: @varkor I get that. Thank you. The links you have attached are helpful.